# Any way to join array in less CSS?

Tags: css, arrays, string, less

The array, list or whatever is called in less:

```
@fonts:
  ~"Droid+Sans:400,700",
  ~"Lato:300,900",
  ~"Open+Sans+Condensed:300,700"
;
```

I want to join all elements in a single string and append it to an url. End result should be:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:400,700|Lato:300,900|Open+Sans+Condensed:300,700);
```

Can less do this?

Answer (score 2):

The most compact way to do that for *this specific use-case* is to use [`replace`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions-replace) function (Less 1.7.+), e.g.:

```css
@fonts:
  ~"Droid+Sans:400,700",
  ~"Lato:300,900",
  ~"Open+Sans+Condensed:300,700"
;

@url-font-list: replace('@{fonts}', ', ', '|', g);
@import url(~"http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=@{url-font-list}");
```

**---**

Alternatively you can join list values via loop but I'm not giving an example here since that method is quite bloating and won't have any advantages over above solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked for a more general method to join list items in LESS, but since it's a declarative language, you can't append list items in a loop (you can't modify any variable in a loop). So, I've tried a recursive approach.

The advantage is that you can use the builtin function `e()` to strip quotes and customize the statement `~"@{a}@{sep}@{b}"` to join items  as you need or reverse their order.

```less
.list-join(@sep, @rest...) {

  ._loop(0, @a) {
    @result: ~"@{a}";
  }
  ._loop(@i, @b) when (@i > 0) {
    @a: e(extract(@rest, @i));
    ._loop(@i - 1, ~"@{a}@{sep}@{b}");
  }
  @num: length(@rest);
  ._loop(@num - 1, e(extract(@rest, @num)));
}
```

Example:

```less
// Fonts list example
@fonts: "Droid+Sans:400,700", "Lato:300,900", "Open+Sans+Condensed:300,700";
@joined: .list-join("|", @fonts)[@result];
@import (css) url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=@{joined}');

test-list-join {
  // Pass list as argument
  @list: "alpha", "bravo", "charlie";
  content: .list-join("-", @list)[@result];

  // Pass list items as multiple arguments
  content: .list-join("-", "a", "b", "c")[@result];
}
```

Output:

```css
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:400,700|Lato:300,900|Open+Sans+Condensed:300,700');
test-list-join {
  content: alpha-bravo-charlie;
  content: a-b-c;
}
```